How can I put Copilot chat back in the main sidebar
In VSCode, Copilot now appears in the second sidebar on the right.
How can I move the Copilot chat back to the main sidebar on the left?
I checked the settings but couldn't find the option. Rolling back the version didn't work either.

I was having the same issue, and stumbled upon this documentation.
You just need to Drag and Drop the icons from the secondary sidebar to the primary like this:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/custom-layout
